# Where do I find a list of changes and bug fixes for .Net classes from 3.5 -> 4.0?

Tags: .net-3.5, .net-4.0

I'm having trouble finding a list of the changes and bug fixes that have been made in the .Net framework for .Net 4.0. They're not easy to find, but surely they exist somewhere?

Specifically I want to find out what changes and updates have been made for `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` and `System.Net.CookieContainer`, as both are quite bugridden in 3.5 and I want to evaluate whether I should write my code for .Net 4.0 or if I should create some custom classes to work around their issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET documentation teams do not publish a list of bug fixes.

You might find something in "What's new" documents such as [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=VS.100).aspx): they usually list not only new features, but also significant improvements.

You can also search on Microsoft Connect. For example: http://connect.microsoft.com/SearchResultsLive.aspx?SearchQuery=HttpWebReques

http://connect.microsoft.com/SearchResultsLive.aspx?SearchQuery=CookieContainer

I don't see that many bugs reported, though. If you have problems with these classes, you should probably submit those at Connect.

Comment: Oh, that's a shame. Thanks for the links though.

Comment: Well, such lists are sometimes published for hot fixes and service packs. I am speaking not just about .NET or even Microsoft. I don't recall any really big product publishing such a list for a new release version.